# multiple collections mongodb to Kafka topic

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

The application writes data every month to a new collection (for example, journal_2205, journal_2206). Is it possible to configure the connector so that it reads the oplog from the new collection and writes to one topic? I use the connector
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/
Thank you!

Comment: It is possible if you have only journal_* collections in the database

Comment: yes, collections has name like journal_*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, you can listen to multiple [change streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/usage-examples/multiple-sources/) from multiple mongo collections. You just need to provide the Regex for the collection names in `pipeline`, you can even provide the Regex for database names if you have multiple databases.

```json
"pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-name$/}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^journal_.*/}}]}}]"
```

You can even exclude any given database using `$nin`, which you dont want to listen for any change-stream.

```json
"pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-name$/,\"$nin\":[/^any_database_name$/]}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^journal_.*/}}]}}]"
```

Here is the complete Kafka connector configuration.

***Mongo to Kafka source connector***

```json
{
  "name": "mongo-to-kafka-connect",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "publish.full.document.only": "true",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "topic.creation.enable": "true",
    "poll.await.time.ms": 1000,
    "poll.max.batch.size": 100,
    "topic.prefix": "any prefix for topic name",
    "output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ip:27017,ip:27017,ip:27017,ip:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=xyz&tls=true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "copy.existing": "true",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 3,
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": 3,
    "topic.creation.compacted.cleanup.policy": "compact",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "mongo.errors.log.enable": "true",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": 10000,
    "pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-name$/}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^journal_.*/}}]}}]"
  }
}
```

You can get more details from official docs.

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html